# Determine the region of overlap after stitching in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching

I am trying to stitching images using this blog [Image Panorama Stitching with OpenCV](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-panorama-stitching-with-opencv-2402bde6b46c)

[image]

[image]

```
# Apply panorama correction
width = trainImg.shape[1] + queryImg.shape[1]
height = trainImg.shape[0] + queryImg.shape[0]

result = cv2.warpPerspective(trainImg, H, (width, height))
result[0:queryImg.shape[0], 0:queryImg.shape[1]] = queryImg
```

Here's Thalles Silva complete [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Md7HWh2ZV6_g3iCYSUw76VNr4HzxcX5#scrollTo=yMNF_uEKE9gj) for Image Panorama Stitching with OpenCV

I would like to know how much of the area of the images actual overlap like in this post [OpenCV determine area of intersect/overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402303/opencv-determine-area-of-intersect-overlap)

[image]

[image]

Where and how should I alter Thalles Silva complete [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11Md7HWh2ZV6_g3iCYSUw76VNr4HzxcX5#scrollTo=yMNF_uEKE9gj) to get the area of intersection, confused?

Comment: You need masks that define the common regions in each image.

Comment: Modify each image so that there is no black. You can just add +1 to each channel. Warp each image to a common output such that the background is black and the rest is still non-black. Then make a mask for each image by changing (thresholding) all non-zero values to white. Use the bitwise_and() to find where the two image overlap.